Drop root permissions in entrypoint of dockerfile
I need to fetch a certificate and update my CAs when my dockerfile starts.
As such, I need USER root in there.
However, I want the rest of my application to run under app.
Is there any way to drop root perms in a way that app can't just exit and get back to root the way putting su - app in my entrypoint script would allow?

Does this answer your question? ENTRYPOINT: first run command as root, then start shell for non-root user

Can you either put your CA certificate in your image (assuming it's just the public certificate), or inject it via some sort of mount?

@DavidMaze - Unfortunately not, it's regenerated every time the cosmos db emulator starts, which is running in another container in the stack
